# Autofilter and remove results in Excel using Apple Script

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am a novice at Apple Script.

I am attempting to auto filter in excel using applescript based on particular states in a certain column.

The code I am using used to work before but not anymore. It was compiled using examples online and in stack overflow.

Below is the problem I am facing.

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
open document file "orders.csv" of folder "Input" of folder "02_Automation" of folder "AAS Orders" of folder "A A Selections 1st June" of folder "Adlina A. Pte Ltd(NEW)" of folder "Fizzy Pop Pte Ltd" of folder "Dropbox (Fizzy Pop)" of folder "zayedtalib" of folder "Users" of startup disk
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set autofilter mode of active sheet to false
    set lastRow to first row index of last row of used range

    autofilter range row ("1:" & lastRow) field 5 criteria1 "(fulfilled)"
    select row ("2:" & lastRow)
    delete selection -- if you want to delete 
    #clear contents selection -- if you only wish to clear the data
end tell
```

end tell

The result from the Script Editor is that error "Microsoft Excel got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist" number -1728 from first row index of last row of used range.

Some help on how to address this would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Adding additional information may be helpful What version of Excel? What platform (Windows? Mac?)

Comment: Thank you Frank. I am using a mac and windows for mac 2011.